# FFT vs Harmonic Analyzer

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, fourier-transform

I watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6dW6VYXp9HM&ab_channel=engineerguy) by Engineer Guy and decided to build the same, but digital. I did it, but I decided to also calculate the sine, to have a complete complex number and be able to calculate the magnitude. So I did and it works fine. Here it is at work: I generated the signal, containing two frequencies, and wrapped it in a nice gaussian spindle:
[image]

Now, here is the result of my Harmonic Analyzer thing, red is sin, blue is cos results:
[image]
Which, when I calculate the magnitude, looks very nice:
[image]

Ok, I love it, but I'd like to compare my slow Analyzer to FFT. I calculate the FFT of the same signal and get this:
[image]

No re/im, but something that looks like a mirrored signal. But the mirrored thing is not exactly the same, if you inspect them closely. I read about it and I gather that maybe the first part is real and the second is imaginary, but flipped? Let's try to calculate it this way:
[image]
Looks similar to mine, but kind of more, I don't know, gnarly. Still, let's find the magnitude to prove the point. Here the magenta is my Harmonic Analyzer magnitudes and yellow - is the FFT's, according to my guess:
[image]
So it's yes! Otherwise, I would not see these two nice gaussian peaks, right? But... Why is it jagged? Why is it not the same as Harmonic Analyzer?
Probably, I sample the sin and cos incorrectly. I sample in the middle, not in the beginning. See this + .5? It should move the "cursor" to the middle of the sample:

```
(frequency: number, i: number) =>  (pi / this.samples.length) * (i + .5) * (frequency);
```

Is this the reason or anything else maybe? I'm puzzled.

The question is: what should I do to convert the result of FFT:
[image]
to an array of real/imaginary pairs? To the result I got from my Harmonics Analyzer:
[image]
?

---

Comment: Your FFT result is what would be expected for a real waveform (The FFT is showing you the components of $e^{j\omega t}$ while a real waveform like a cosine has two such components-- consider Euler's formula: $2\cos(\omega t) = e^{j\omega t} + e^{-j\omega t}$ (so we see from the exponent and positive and negative freq). With the FFT, the upper half equivalently represents the magnitude and phase of the negative frequency components.  If your test waveform was done with sines and cosines, combine them as a complex waveform: $\cos(\omega t) + j\sin(\omega t)$ and then take the FFT.

Comment: (I have no idea why your result is jagged without seeing more specifics, so didn't provide a complete answer below).

Comment: The question is: what should I do to convert the result of FFT (this mirrored-ish array of numbers, red graph) to an array of real/imaginary pairs? To the result I got from my Harmonics Analyzer (the first graph with red and blue lines, red is real, blue is imaginary)?